# Como acrescentar um número sequencial em elementos repetidos

Tags: string, if, for

Suponha o seguinte df

```
testeID <- c("111", "222", "333", "444")
testeGRAFIA <- c("AUTOR A", "AUTOR B", "AUTOR B","AUTOR C")
TesteIGUAL <- data.frame(testeID,testeGRAFIA)
TesteIGUAL$AutorDif<-NA
```

Eu preciso que na coluna *AutorDif* sejam retornados os elementos repetidos da coluna *testeGRAFIA*, com o acréscimo de um numeral sequencial.
Os demais elementos da coluna *testeGRAFIA* - que não forem repetidos -, podem ser reescritos.

Ou seja, meu resultado esperado seria:

```
   AutorDif
1     AUTOR A
2     AUTOR B
3     AUTOR B**1**
4     AUTOR C
```

No meu esboço de solução, iniciei a estruturação de um *for*:

```
i=1
for (i in 1:nrow(TesteIGUAL)) {
  TesteIGUAL$AutorDif[i]<-
    if(

    )
      else
}
```

Nesse *for*, uma possível solução seria usar o *str_pad*, como no exemplo abaixo:

```
TesteIGUAL$AutorDif<-str_pad(string=TesteIGUAL$AutorDif,side = "right", width = nchar(TesteIGUAL$testeGRAFIA)+1, pad = (??????))
```

Porém, não sei que função escrever ali no "pad".

Alguém teria alguma ideia de como resolver isso?

Comment: Favor informe a linguagem de programação ou script...

Comment: Boa noite, Ricardo. Estou fazendo no RStudio